# how can we find value of c in big theta

Tags: algorithm, big-o

According to the definition, we say that f(n) is θ(g(n)) for some n ≥ no=1;
c>0 the how can we find the value c in big 0 and big omega 
 for example;-

```
c1.n≥8n+2≥c2.n
```

in this equation we can find value of c1 in big o while adding all the constants very easy but how can we find big omega c2 to find big theta.

Answer (score 0):

With Big-O, you need to look at an inequality to find its constant c1: f(n) <= c1*g(n), for all n >= n_0.

In Big-Omega, you also need to look at another inequality to find the constant c2: f(n) >= c2*g(n), for all n >= n_0.

**It's similar to the process for Big-O**, why is it harder?